# Class included correctly not found

Tags: php, include

It works with Dreamweaver but not in my site.

I have this hierarchy:

phpfiles/

*_*_best/

_*_*****tile.php

_*_*****bestcartile.php

*_*_templates/

_*_*****leftcolumn.php

tile.php and bestcartile.php define the classes Tile and BestCarTile(a subclass of Tile).

Some code, **bestcartile.php**

```
<?php
include 'tile.php';

class BestCarTile extends Tile{
private $bestCars;

    public function __construct($dbConn){
        $this->query($dbConn);
        parent::__construct(. . . .); //Some parameters
    }

    private function query($dbConn){
        //Si sceglie l'auto più votata.
        $query = $dbConn->query(. . . .); //A query
        $this->bestCars = $query->fetch_array();
    }
}
?>
```

}

**leftcolumn.php**

```
<?php
include '../best/bestcartile.php';

//Connessione a MySQL
$dbConn = new mysqli(. . . .);

$bestcartile = new BestCarTile($dbConn);
$bestcartile->display();

$dbConn->close();

?>
```

The error is:

Fatal error: Class 'BestCarTile' not found

Comment: Try `require_once` instead of `include`. I'll bet you'll get an error that the file could not be found.

Comment: Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '../best/bestcartile.php' (include_path='.:') in /members/username/phpfiles/templates/leftcolumn.php on line 2

Comment: See, told ya. The file is not where you think it is.

Comment: Fatal Error shows that you are try to get that class which is not defined.Please check your file path. and in bestcartile.php file the closing of class '}' is outside of php. Please put it inside. Hope it will help you.

Comment: My file path is correct and in fact with dreamweaver which is synchronized with my site works. I use Joomla and Jumi plugin to use php code. Maybe it's a bug of Jumi.

Answer (score 0):

It´s seens that you´re get this behavior because BesteCarTile class block is not being closed correctly. So you´re trying to call a class inside itself.

```
<?php
include 'tile.php';

class BestCarTile extends Tile {
   private $bestCars;

   public function __construct($dbConn){
    $this->query($dbConn);
    parent::__construct(. . . .); //Some parameters
   }

   private function query($dbConn){
    //Si sceglie l'auto più votata.
    $query = $dbConn->query(. . . .); //A query
    $this->bestCars = $query->fetch_array();
   }
} // Missing 
?>
```

Can you check that?

Best Regards

Comment: Sorry, but in reality the parenthesis is present in my code. I missed it in the copy and paste. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Fatal Error shows that you are try to get that class which is not defined.Please check your file path. and in bestcartile.php file the closing of class '}' is outside of php. Please put it inside. Hope it will help you.